# Run python selenium chromedriver as systemd service

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver

I have selenium parser that works on chromedriver. When I start it in bash, it works good. But when I start service. It returns
`The version of chrome cannot be detected. Trying with latest driver version`
 `(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`

I tried to change PATH variable and checked that my chrome is last version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on macOS while running a python script from a cronjob. I had to modify the `PATH` env variable so the script could run:

```
PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/bin python3 ...
```

But it was very slow and the same `The version of chrome cannot be detected` error would pop up with every run.

The solution for me was to add `/bin` to the `PATH`. The cron job now looks like this

```
PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/bin:/bin python3 ...
```

The error message is gone and the script is much faster now. Hope that does the trick for you too.